# $_SESSION destroy german Umlauts

Tags: php, session

theres a problem with german Umlauts in $_SESSION. I do following:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['name']= 'abcüdef'   // where ü is a german umlaut
header("Location: AnotherScript.php");
die();
?>
```

The redirect works fine, but in AnotherScript.php the 'ü' in $_SESSION is changed.

AnotherScript.php is like this:

```
<php
echo $_SESSION['name'];   // shows abc?def
?>
```

The files are coded in utf8 without DOM,
the charset in both files is utf8.

If i call AnotherScript.php via a button in html (not via header) everything is fine.
Guess the header("Location: AnotherScript.php"); don't give the used charset to the called script. I tried something like this: header("Location: AnotherScript.php; charset=utf-8"), but its not working.
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8'); before or after session_start(); has no effect.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: do you use it ? => header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Yes, i do. In both files.

Comment: Please show a complete reproducible example.
session_start() is also missing. And For pure php file do not use the close tag <? at the end

Comment: What character encoding did you save the PHP script files in?

Comment: Its utf8 without DOM - but thanks for help, i did a workaround. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to depend on the used server, on my local server its works fine.
So thank you for helping - i did a workaround:
After every session_start(); i run:

```
if (mb_detect_encoding($_SESSION['name']) == 'UTF-8') // may only be decoded once!
    $_SESSION['name']= utf8_encode($_SESSION['name']);
```

Comment: Also be sure that your HTTP headers include `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.